# Jquery/javascript Radio button hide/show logic for checked attribute for pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I was trying to code jquery/JS logic for hide/show description based on radio button being checked or not. If the radio button is checked on page load, i want the description associated with that radio button to load. But the default one of the either has to selected/checked

I did try to code with .change and click methods inside ready(). But was not successful

I have only two radio buttons, I'm not a Javascript/jquery person. Any input is appreciated. This is an example

```
<div id="ServiceSelection">     
 <input type="radio" name="Service" checked="Checked" value="B"> Option 1
  <br>
 <input type="radio" name="Service" value="P"> Option 2
  <br>
  <div id="DivB" style="display:none" class="desc">B  Description goes here </div>
 <div id="DivP" style="display:none" class="desc">P Description goes here </div>    
</div>
```

Edited DIV:

```
<div id="ServiceSelection">     
<input type="radio" name="Service" checked="Checked" value="B"> Option 1
<br>
<div id="DivB" style="display:none" class="desc">B  Description goes here </div>
<input type="radio" name="Service" value="P"> Option 2
<br>
<div id="DivP" style="display:none" class="desc">P Description goes here </div>    
</div>
```

Thanks in advance
J

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('input[name=Service]').is(':checked')){ //is it checked?
    var v = $('input[name=Service]:checked').val(); //get the value
    $('div[id$='+v+']').show(); //target the end of selector, and match it to our value
}

$('input[name=Service]').on('click', function(){
   $(this).parent().find('div').hide(); //hide the divs...
   $('div[id$='+$(this).val()+']').show(); //show the div based on our value again..
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpv4X/)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this with the new DIV I just posted. It works fine when I demo it on fiddle but on the actual page, should I wrap it in document.load method? which I did. On the page load, the I see the first option but when I click/change the option, I dont see the second test showing up...what could be the problem? @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ShowData(evt) {
    var val = $("input[name=Service]:checked").val();
    if (val == 'B') {
        $('#DivB').show();
        $('#DivP').hide();
    } else {
        $('#DivP').show();
        $('#DivB').hide();
    }
}

$('input[name=Service]:radio').change(ShowData);
ShowData();
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2gVEm/)

Comment: Thanks for the input...  I tried this with the new DIV I just posted. It works fine when I demo it on fiddle but on the actual page, should I wrap it in document.load method? or some other method? @will.i.am

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
// hide the div elements with JavaScript, so they're visible to those
// users with JavaScript disabled:
$('#ServiceSelection div[id]').hide();

// select the radio input elements and bind to the change event
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    // find the element whose id is equal to 'Div' + the value of the radio,
    // show that div, hide the sibling div elements
    $('#Div' + this.value).show().siblings('div').hide();
// filter the radio elements to find the one that's checked, and trigger the change event
}).filter(function(){return this.checked; }).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nd7aq/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`hide
  ()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: Thanks for the Input @David Thomas. But the actual page has JS enabled which is a JSP. Should I wrap the code you suggested around the above solutions?